# XRDP Desktop does not look same as Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop

I followed these awesome instructions for installing XRDP on Ubuntu 18.04:

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04/

I was expecting a desktop mirror of what i normally see on my Ubnuntu Desktop. It looks completely different when I log on. What can/should i do if i want a 'mirrored ' experience?

Mark

Comment: XRDP only works with the XCFE desktop environment, your standard Ubuntu desktop environment is Unity/GNOME driven.  They're completely different environments.  Only way to 'mirror' your Ubuntu Desktop experience is to use VNC, not RDP, to connect to the system.

Comment: To add to the above, I get great results with x11vnc. There are countless tutorials out there. I usually use the RealVNC (proprietary, I know) VNC Viewer as it 'just works'.

Comment: @ThomasWard Someone has written a [script](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15733) to make XRDP work with GNOME in Ubuntu.

Comment: @user68186 that sounds like an answer to file.  However, the script needs some revisions - it forces users to use `be.archive.ubuntu.com` for things which... probably shouldn't be the case :P  I'm testing the script now locally in VMs to see how it works and such.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWard one reason I didn't put it as answer was because I was not sure about the script and wanted some one with more experience like you check if out. The author says in the blog, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @ThomasWard.  The script is being updated so the user is not forced to be.archive.ubuntu.com...Updated script version will be released probably in January 2021 as we are still working on it and introducing some minor changes... Suggestions are always welcomed... Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be expected if you simply perform a manual installation of xrdp package.  Assuming that you are using Gnome Desktop, you would need to perform some additional configuration changes in order to have same look'n feel in your remote session as when locally logged on on your Ubuntu machine....

To have the same look n feel, you have multiple options.  We usually create a file called .xsessionrc and we populate it with something like

```
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
```

This would be for a single user.  You can also use the **xrdp-installer** script that basically perform the installation of the software and perform some post configuration actions that would provide you the same look'n feel when remotely connected as the one you have when connected to local console

the script and how to use it can be found [here](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15733)

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya

Comment: This looks like a great answer! I kinda need to caveat my 'mark as answer' I installed the script with arguments '-s -l' I got the custom logon so I know your software had an effect.m But I did not get my expected Bionic Beaver desktop. I can try the .xsessionrc instructions but where does that file belong?

Comment: okay i found my .xsessionrc in my home directory as hidden:

Comment: export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg

Comment: After some Griffon Aided tweeking this is a great solution - Highly recomended